# How to link with boost on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to link my project with boost compute and I've met with follow issue:
`LNK1104 could not open file "libboost_chrono-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_80.lib"`

My cmake file:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "D:\\Tools\\boost_1_80_0")
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)

find_package(Boost 1.80.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options chrono)
```

As far as I understood issue happens due to different msvc toolsets, but when I configure project with:

```
"generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022 Win64"
{
  "name": "CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET",
  "type": "STRING",
  "value": "v141"
}
```

configuration fails. As workaround I just copy and renamed chrono lib, and it seems working but it hack.
**How to correctly link boost on windows in cmake project?**

Comment: Download/build the boost libraries with the same compiler that you're using

Comment: The generator toolset `v141` should be `v143` for Visual Studio 17 2022. Setting toolset to `v141` means using the VC 2017 compiler in the VS 2022 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

yes, thx, didn't see that there is version with v143 as well https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.80.0_b1/